# Replicating a plot in R

Tags: r, replicate

I am solving a task for my R online course. The task is to create and save the following pdf-file by given the functions of X and Y and test it with Reg(50) and set.seed(1423):

[image: PDF-Goal-File]

The first step is to create the basic Reg()-function, that creates only one plot. It looks like this:

```
Reg<-function(Anzahl){
  set.seed(1423)
  if(Anzahl<0|!(is.numeric(Anzahl)&&floor(Anzahl)==Anzahl))stop("Schreiben Sie eine positive ganze Zahl")
  X<-runif(Anzahl,min=0,max=20)
  Y<-3-0.2*X+rnorm(Anzahl,0,1)
  model<-lm(Y~X,data=data.frame(X=X,Y=Y))
  object<-paste0("Gleichung: y(x)=",round(coef(model)[[1]],2)," ",round(coef(model)[[2]],2),"*x")
  plot(X,Y,axes=F,xlab=NA,ylab=NA,cex=0.8,pch=24,bg="darkblue",main=paste0("Regressionsanalyse \n",object))
  axis(side=1,at=c(0,5,10,15,20),col=NA,cex.axis=1.2)
  axis(side=2,at=c(seq((min(Y)%%2==T)*min(Y)+floor(min(Y))-1,(max(Y)%%2==T)*max(Y)+ceiling(max(Y))+1,2)),col=NA,las=1,cex.axis=1.2)
  mtext(side=1,"Unabhängige Variable",line=2,cex=1.1)
  mtext(side=2,"Abhängige Variable",line=2,cex=1.1)
  abline(lm(Y~X),col="red",lwd=2)
  grid()
}
```

The task is to use the replicate()-function to create 9 randomly generated plots (like those in the picture) and to save them in one pdf-file, as similar as possible to the picture. For that purpose the margins of one plot inside the plot region are 0.5 in on the top, the bottom and the left and 0.1 in on the right.

How can I use the replicate()-function to get the output?

Comment: All of the data is the given picture and the functions: X<-runif(Anzahl,min=0,max=20), Y<-3-0.2*X+rnorm(Anzahl,0,1), as well as the set.seed(1423). The idea is to recreate the file as similar as possible to the original.

Answer (score 1):

The `pdf` functions in `grDevices` can be used for switching to a pdf file as the graphics context. Plotting multiple graphs on the same page/frame is achieved by `par(mfrow = c(nrow,ncol)`, so that `nrow * ncol` plots are stacked in a `nrow x ncol` grid in the same frame. The `replicate` function is used for repeated evaluation of an expression. So, this should work:

```
> pdf("Regplots.pdf")
> par(mfrow = c(3,3))
> dummy=replicate(9, Reg(50))
> dev.off()
pdf 
  2 
>
```

One issue is that you are setting the seed inside the function to be called, which generates the observation, fits the models, and creates the plots. This would result in the exact same observations being generated every time, which is likely not the point of this exercise, as the plots in the picture you attached vary slightly among themselves. Instead, set the seed outside before the replicate call.

```
> Reg<-function(Anzahl){
+   if(Anzahl<0|!(is.numeric(Anzahl)&&floor(Anzahl)==Anzahl))stop("Schreiben Sie eine positive ganze Zahl")
+   X<-runif(Anzahl,min=0,max=20)
+   Y<-3-0.2*X+rnorm(Anzahl,0,1)
+   model<-lm(Y~X,data=data.frame(X=X,Y=Y))
+   object<-paste0("Gleichung: y(x)=",round(coef(model)[[1]],2)," ",round(coef(model)[[2]],2),"*x")
+   plot(X,Y,axes=F,xlab=NA,ylab=NA,cex=0.8,pch=24,bg="darkblue",main=paste0("Regressionsanalyse \n",object))
+   axis(side=1,at=c(0,5,10,15,20),col=NA,cex.axis=1.2)
+   axis(side=2,at=c(seq((min(Y)%%2==T)*min(Y)+floor(min(Y))-1,(max(Y)%%2==T)*max(Y)+ceiling(max(Y))+1,2)),col=NA,las=1,cex.axis=1.2)
+   mtext(side=1,"Unabhängige Variable",line=2,cex=1.1)
+   mtext(side=2,"Abhängige Variable",line=2,cex=1.1)
+   abline(lm(Y~X),col="red",lwd=2)
+   grid()
+ }
> 
> pdf("Regplots.pdf")
> set.seed(1423)
> par(mfrow = c(3,3))
> dummy=replicate(9, Reg(50))
> dev.off()
pdf 
  2
```

[image: Generated plot in pdf]

P.S. The `bg` parameter should be set to `"blue"` for the colour of the points in the image you attached: `"darkblue"` becomes too dark in the pdf file for some reason.

Edit: From https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html:
"If you are going to create a custom axis, you should suppress the axis automatically generated by your high level plotting function. The option axes=FALSE suppresses both x and y axes. xaxt="n" and yaxt="n" suppress the x and y axis respectively."

You can fix y axis labels to only even numbers using the methods described in the link. For setting the plot margin, `par` has the arguments `mar` and `mai` for margins in text width and inches (supply only one) - as a numeric vector in the order bottom, left, top and right, but it doesn't seem to work as desired here.

Comment: Much better than my attempt.

Comment: It worked - however I have two questions: is there a way to fix the y-axis to only show even numbers, because the code: axis(side=2,at=c(seq((min(Y)%%2==T)*min(Y)+floor(min(Y))-1,(max(Y)%%2==T)*max(Y)+ceiling(max(Y))+1,2)),col=NA,las=1,cex.axis=1.2) doesn't work and the y-axis changes it's value. The second question is, is it possible to set the margin of each plot inside the plot region to 0.5 in on the top, on the bottom, on the left and 0.1 in on the right?